# How could I replace some | by :?

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Hello I have this kind of lines in my text :

```
Test | (4079|5657|5914)
```

And I would like by a regex to have this :

```
Test | (4079:5657:5914)
```

I tried this

replace this : `([0-9](3)|[0-9](3)|[0-9](3))`
by this : `([0-9](3):[0-9](3):[0-9](3))`

but it does not work...

Thank you very much !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Note that to match 3 consecutive digits you need to use`[0-9]{3}`. Can there be more numbers inside parentheses? Can there be other numbers? Like `(23|234|42353|43234|3)`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this find and replace:

```
Find:    \((\d+)\|(\d+)\|(\d+)\)
Replace: ($1:$2:$3)
```

This appears to be working in a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/72ohQM/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Find and Replace with regex

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> in Sublime Text
- Select **Regular expression**
- Enter the following

  **Find:** `(\d+)\|`

  **Replace:** `$1:`
- Hit **Replace All**

[image]

Input:

```
Test | (4079|5657|5914)
Test | (4079|5657|5914|1224344|123)
```

Output

```
Test | (4079:5657:5914)
Test | (4079:5657:5914:1224344:123)
```